# Deploy php with ldap.conf

Tags: php, azure, ldap, openldap, ldapconnection

I'm using php 7 to connect to active directory using LDAP. I need to create manually a file under: C:\openLDAP\sysconf\ldap.conf and set TLS_REQCERT never. If I don't create this file ldap fails to connect.

How can I deploy this to, for example, azure machine that not includes C: disk?

Do you know a better aproach to solve this error?

I tried this:
[Need help ignoring server certificate while binding to LDAP server using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866406/need-help-ignoring-server-certificate-while-binding-to-ldap-server-using-php)

```
   putenv('LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never');
```

But it doesn't works.

Comment: PHP 7.1 has options for this you can set without the config file, but I'm guessing you're stuck on PHP 7.0? You could connect to a console session of your webapp via the portal and figure out what your users home directory is and place a `.ldaprc` file in that location with the options you need. Or run a PHP file over the console with your LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC turned to 7 and see where it's looking for the config files.

Comment: Thank you very much for your awnser but one question, do you know how can I deploy openLDAP on a azure windows server automatically without an executable?

Answer (score 1):

I know its years but i had the same issue and this was what i did, which is what @ChadSikorra has said.

1. place a .php script in site root (i did test/ldap.php) that has your connections to ldap, add the code below before the `php ldap_connect()`

   ```php
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);

   error_reporting(E_ALL);

   ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
   ```
2. using Kudu CMD from site root, cd test, php ldap.php

this was the results

[image: ldap.php logs]

3. Notice the 5th red line, Navigate to D:/ and create `.ldaprc` file
4. edit the file and paste `TLS_REQCERT never` , save, repeat step 2.
5. If your application is running, go to the application console and restart the server.

Done!

complete ldap.php file below

```
$username = "USERNAME";
$password = "PASSWORD";
$adServer = "IP"; //or domain
$adPort = 389;
$ldaprdn = "DOMAIN\\$username";

ldap_set_optioNULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);

putenv('LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never');

$ldap = ldap_connect("ldaps://$adServer", $adPort);

ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

$bind = ldap_bind($ldap, $ldaprdn, $password);

if ($bind) {
    echo "Connection successful";
    @ldap_close($ldap);
} else {
    echo "Invalid email address / password";
}
```

Comment: Never, ever use TLS_REQUCERT=never unless you know **exactly** what you are doing. YOu are opening up your connection to MITM-attacks. [I blogged](https://andreas.heigl.org/2020/01/31/handle-self-signed-certificates-with-phps-ldap-extension/) about alternative solutions

Comment: in my case, this was sitting as a service within a closed network. For Applications such as web apps, Please ignore that line. Thanks @heiglandreas

Comment: So you knew exactly what you were doing ;-)